# onsubmit doesn't call javascript function

Tags: javascript, validation

I have checked recent blogs about onsubmit event not triggering the method. Those suggestions were not helpful for this problem.And i've tried this method and form in an another html page which didn't work either.So i am not able to find out where main problem is ? My code :

```
    <script>
    function validateLogin()
    {
        var nameCheck=document.Log.username.value;
        var passwordCheck=document.Log.password.value;
        var status=false;

        if(nameCheck.length<4)
        {
            document.Log.getElementById("nameLoc").innerHTML=
            'Put your Email Address for this Community\'s Sake';
            status=false;

        }
        else
        {
            document.Log.getElementById("nameLoc").innerHTML=
            'Naming Convention Allright';
            status=true;
        }

        if(passwordCheck.length<8)
        {
            document.Log.getElementById("passwordLoc").innerHTML=
            'Password Does not Meet with Standard';
            status=false;
        }
        else
        {
            document.Log.getElementById("passwordLoc").innerHTML=
            'Passowrd Convention Allright';
            status=true;
        }
        return status;
    }
    </script>

    <form name="Log" method="post" action="login.php" onsubmit="return 
    validateLogin()">
      <div class="imgcontainer">
        <img src="login.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" 
        required><span id="nameLoc"></span>
        <br>
        <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label><span id="passwordLoc">
        </span>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" 
         required><span id="passwordLoc"></span>
            <br>  
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> 
               Remember      me
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: An obvious bug is that the `nameCheck.length` test is ignored, as the subsequent `passwordCheck.length` test overwrites it.

Comment: not exactly ignored, as the code is executed, but it has no influence on the returned status

Comment: @Thomas That's what you call a distinction without a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `getElementById` on the `form` - but it is a function of the `document`.

Change to this:

```
if (nameCheck.length < 4) {
                document.getElementById("nameLoc").innerHTML =
                    'Put your Email Address for this Community\'s Sake';
                status = false;

            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("nameLoc").innerHTML =
                    'Naming Convention Allright';
                status = true;
            }

            if (passwordCheck.length < 8) {
                document.getElementById("passwordLoc").innerHTML =
                    'Password Does not Meet with Standard';
                status = false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("passwordLoc").innerHTML =
                    'Passowrd Convention Allright';
                status = true;
            }
```

Comment: This is something new to me. Called the function within the script tag and it gave an error the same. So, if the function is called from an event, is there no way to catch any errors the function might throw?

Comment: @powersource97, I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Can you exapnd a little?

Comment: @StevePadmore Like you mentioned, the script code had an error, in that, OP was trying to call a function which wasn't defined for the form. So, ideally that gives an error when executed right? (Tried by calling the function separately, it did give an error.) But in this case, console had no error messages. So, if a function is triggered by an event, maybe a form submit event, if it encounters errors while executing, will it not inform of the error, by printing it out to console? Because if it did, OP could have solved that issue by himself :)

Comment: Ah, I see. You could handle any error using window.onerror, or you could try/catch in the function and return false on error, preventing the form submitting.

Answer (score 1):

Just add value in your button like below :-

```
  <button type="submit" value="submit>Login</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have added value but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to your form in the script tag and it will work:

`document.Log.addEventListener("submit", validateLogin);`

PS: For this, you will need to move your script tag to below your form, because Log isn't defined as far as the code is concerned until the form loads before the code is run.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know if your function is called? Put an alert in there to make sure!

Your validate function will allow the submission to continue if either condition is met. You should change it to initialise status to true then set it to false in both negative results but don't set it back to true for positive.

If it still doesn't work you could put your call in the onclick event of the submit button instead.